# NServiceBus: How to not create queues automatically

Tags: nservicebus

I really want to be able to prevent NSB from creating my queues automatically.  I don’t like how it creates them with totally unrestricted permissions.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

You can provide your custom initialization code by implementing IWantCustomInitialization and specifying it in your code:

```
void IWantCustomInitialization.Init()
    {
        NServiceBus.Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .MsmqTransport()
            .DoNotCreateQueues()
            .XmlSerializer();
    }
```